# Geo Point data in ElasticSearch/Kibana from Python app

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana

I have a python app and let's suppose I'd like to send to the ELK stack traffic data from my app, so that I visualize my traffic in a map, using kibana map tiles.

My code is:

```
es = ElasticSearch(hosts=["here is my host"])
doc = {
    'timestamp': datetime.now(),
    "text": "Geo-point as an object",
    "location": {
        "lat": 41.12,
        "lon": -71.34
    }
}
res = es.index(index="test", doc_type='request-info', body=doc)
```

Unluckily though Kibana doesn't recognise it a geo point, so I cannot create any visualization on a map. Specifically it returns an error of `"The "index name" index pattern does not contain any of the following field types: geo_point"`.

How should I implement such thing, has anybody any ideas about this?

Thanks in advance

ps: I use this python lib `https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create the [mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html) first. *Location* is being treated as *string* type rather than [*geo_point*](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html) type.

Try the following code

```
es = ElasticSearch(hosts=["here is my host"])
mapping = {
        "mappings": {
            "request-info": {
                "properties": {
                    "timestamp": {
                        "type": "date"
                    },
                    "text": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "location": {
                        "type": "geo_point"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
es.indices.create(index='test', body=mapping)
doc = {
    'timestamp': datetime.now(),
    "text": "Geo-point as an object",
    "location": {
        "lat": 41.12,
        "lon": -71.34
    }
}
res = es.index(index="test", doc_type='request-info', body=doc)
```

Comment: you were right, it worked now! So I missed the mapping creation step, I had been thinking this would be done automatically but obviously, I was wrong. Thanks for your help!

Comment: glad I could help

Comment: @ChintanShah25, I had same problem which convert numbers to geo-points. I followed your steps, but still not getting correct results. My question posted as  "Why does geospatial data not convert from numbers to geo-point with Python client with Elastisearch?". Could you help me please?